# Render .obj using NFT markers

Tags: android-studio, artoolkit

I am using ARToolkit and trying to render the .obj using NFT marker in android.
In examples they are using .osg for NFT markers and .obj is rendered using traditional square markers.
Can any body help me to render .obj using NFT markers.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendering and the marker are completely independent. When you specify a marker, you use a string that defines the type, size and file.

You can get the example that renders obj and just change the string that defines the marker and make it be a NFT marker.

Note: Please remember that ARToolKit generates a cache of the files under assets that is regenerated when you raise the versionNumber of the app, so if you add new files under assets, you need to increase the versionNumber for them to be found.

Comment: i tried    arwAddMarker("nft;DataNFT/pinball")  in the ARWrapperNativeCarsExample.cpp. but its not working!!!

Comment: Have you added the files to assets? Also, have you raised the app version number (ARToolkit uses a cache that is only recreated when the version number increases) or uninstalling the app (which obviously clears that cache)

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the original answer to include the information of the cache.